# extjs automatic date parsing in store object

Tags: javascript, extjs

Using extjs 3.4. I have a json object that is parsed in the store.

```
"date_end":{"date":31,"day":5,"hours":0,"minutes":0,"month":11,"seconds":0,"time":253402210800000,"timezoneOffset":-60,"year":8099}
```

This is my store fields:

```
fields: [{name:'date_end.time',type:"date",dateFormat:"time"}]
```

It works, but with this solution I must specify the `type` and `dateFormat` configurations.

Is possbible to use an automatic configuration? something like this:

```
fields: [{name:'date_end.time'}]
```

or better:

```
fields: [{name:'date_end'}]
```

So, is possible to use minum configuration options?

Answer (score 0):

You can globally override the dateFormat on the field object:

```
Ext.override(Ext.data.DataField, {
    dateFormat: 'time'
});
```

As for the type, no, you can't, you need to specify it.